# secure curl POST

Tags: post, curl

in my new script i am using two servers ..

one for database and php files

and one for files uploaded by users , like exe , mp3 , etc ..

from control panel on the first server , they can delete them files on the second server ..

my question is :

i am using curl to do this job

i am sending 2 POST information by curl

1 - some password for my site
2 - the job what i want do ! , like , delete file , make new folder ...

```
examples for the curl function :
$post = array('password'=>'Mywebsitepassword','command'=>'make new folder');
```

example for the file on the second server

```
if($_POST['password'] and $_POST['password'] == Mywebsitepassword){
  it's ok
}
```

Now the password is 'Mywebsitepassword'

can any one know it ?????

if some one can know it , he will be able to delete all my second server content !!

is any addone or some way to know it ??

may be some addone for firefox can know it or something like that

and what is the best way to secure this job ?

thank you ..

Comment: my website Cpanel is '9118200' but try to find the domain :)

Comment: according to your profile it is: google.com ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you do your stuff over a secure connection (SSL).

**EDIT**

Tutorial of creating self signed certificate on Linux: http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

on Windows: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(WS.10).aspx

Comment: it's hard to get licanse ,, what about sessions ? can i set session on the second server via first server ?

Comment: Sessions won't protect the data that is being send from server to server. Only SSL is. You can create a self-signed certificate yourself for free.

Comment: can you tell me how to get the free version ?

Comment: NEW IDEA : refuse or block all requests from all ips ! only me first server ip can be accepted ! what about this idea ?

Comment: @Osama Tarek: you could do that, however an IP address can be spoofed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing

Comment: damn .. so what about the self-signed certificate .. can you tell me more about ?